# Why is my `StandardOleMarshalObject` COM Object called from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a COM object which is implemented in C#, and inherits from `StandardOleMarshalObject` to disable the NTA default behavior.  For some reason, when I make a call to a server that makes a reentrant call to the client, the callback ends up on a different thread.

How do I ensure that all calls are made on the main thread?

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IComChat
{
    void WriteLine(string text);
    void Subscribe(IComChat callback);
}

public class ComChatServer : StandardOleMarshalObject, IComChat
{
    private List<IComChat> Clients = new List<IComChat>();

    public void WriteLine(string text)
    {
        foreach (var client in Clients)
        {
            // this makes a reentrant callback into the calling client
            client.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe(IComChat client) => Clients.Add(client);
}

public class ComChatClient : StandardOleMarshalObject, IComChat
{
    private IComChat Server;
    private Thread MainThread;

    public ComChatClient()
    {
        this.MainThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        this.Server = /* get server by some means */;

        this.Server.Subscribe(this);
    }

    void IComChat.WriteLine(string text)
    {
        // this throws as the call ends up on a different thread
        Contract.Assert(Thread.CurrentThread == MainThread);

        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    void IComChat.Subscribe(IComChat callback) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public void WriteLine(string text) => Server.WriteLine(text);
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new ComChatClient();
        Application.Run(new ChatWindow(client));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StandardOleMarshalObject` only keeps things on the main thread if you create the object on a STA thread.  Mark your entrypoint with `[STAThread]` to set your main thread as being single-threaded:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new ComChatClient();
        Application.Run(new ChatWindow(client));
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what you should **never** do.  [STAThread] is a *promise*, you swear cross-your-heart-hope-to-die that your thread is well-behaved and supports code that is not thread-safe.  Like your ComChatClient.  But you promptly violated that promise, you do not pump a message loop as required by STA.  So originally COM created a thread to give your object a safe home, one that follows the rules.  The consequence of the lie is deadlock.  Can be the *very* ugly kind, a deadlocked finalizer thread is pretty hard to diagnose.

Comment: @HansPassant, the application itself did pump messages on the "main" thread.  I just missed that in the example code.  The idiocy I was lambasting myself for was a missing `STAThreadAttribute`.

Comment: Hmya, using a project template to get started *does* avoid many accidents.  Having UI that looks like it came from the previous century isn't that pretty either.